# Attaining the marginal probability function

Tags: probability

Suppose X, Y are discrete random variables with joint probability mass function

$$
f(n) =
\begin{cases}
1/10,  & \text{if $1\leq y\leq x \leq 4$ } \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Why is the marginal probability mass function for random variable Y, equate to the following? More specifically, if by definition marginal probability function is attained by summation of all the X's, why start from Y and not 1?

$$f_y = \sum_x f(x,y) = \sum_y^4 \frac{1}{10} $$

Comment: Because $f(x,y)=0$ for every $x<y$.

Comment: Would this be different for probability density functions? @Did

Comment: What? Please stay focussed on your question. Is it answered?

Comment: @Did yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, in the joint mass function, $f(n)$ should be something like $f(x,y)$, as mass function determined the probability of a combination of events $X=x$ and $Y=y$. This joint mass function assigns equal probabilities to each possible $(x,y)$ pairs in the domain, namely $(1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (4,1), (2,2), (3,2), (4,2), (3,3), (4,3), (4,4)$ (notice that these give you a "lower-diagonal" matrix, if you wrote them in a triangular form).

Generally, it may be a good exercise to include the indices, resulting in less confusion.

Say we want to find $f_Y(n)$ for some $n \in \{1,2,3,4\}$. Then for this fixed $n$, there are possible values $X$ can take, but as we don't care what value $X$ will take in the marginal mass function of $Y$, we need to add all possible cases, for example,

$$
P(Y = 1) = P(Y=1,X=1) + P(Y=1,X=2) + P(Y=1,X=3) + P(Y=1,X=4).
$$

This is why the sum is over possible values of $X$. Then

$$
f_Y(n) = \sum_{k=1}^4 f(k,n) =  \sum_{k=1}^4 P(X=k, Y=n) 
$$

But since $P(X=k, Y=n)=0$ for $k<n$, you can start the sum from $n$, instead of $1$, as otherwise you are just adding zeroes. Thus,

$$
f_Y(n) = \sum_{k=n}^4 f(k,n) =  \sum_{k=n}^4 P(X=k, Y=n) =  \sum_{k=n}^4 \frac{1}{10},
$$

e.g.,

$$
f_Y(3) = \sum_{k=3}^4 f(k,n) =  P(X=3, Y=3) + P(X=4, Y=3) = \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{10} = \frac{2}{10}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Try adding up the joint probabilities in a row for a given $y$ to get the marginal probability for $Y=y$.  You start with positive values when $x=y$ and go through to $x=4$

```
    x        1    2   3    4    Margin y 
y  

1          1/10 1/10 1/10 1/10    4/10
2           0   1/10 1/10 1/10    3/10 
3           0    0   1/10 1/10    2/10
4           0    0    0   1/10    1/10

Margin x   1/10 2/10 3/10 4/10
```